# How to show only the children in WordPress Categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I have this code for WordPress and this code only displays the entire category list. I want to make it only show the categories' children category (not display "all").

Right now I have:
Category Page 1

-child1

-child2

Category Page 2

-child1

-child2

**For example that is what I want:

Category Page 1

-child1

Category Page 2

-child2**

```
<!-- Gallery filters -->
<div id="gallery_filter">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_page_link(df_get_page("gallery-1", false)));?>"<?php if(!$catSlug) { ?> class="active"<?php } ?>><?php esc_html_e("All", THEME_NAME);?></a>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <?php if(isset($category->term_id)) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_term_link((int)$category->term_id,DF_POST_GALLERY.'-cat'));?>"<?php if($catSlug==$category->slug) { ?> class="active"<?php } ?>><?php echo esc_html__($category->name);?></a>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You really should change the title of this question. It's incredibly unclear and will get voted down.

Comment: Probably the best question title (though [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942390/plese-provide-solution) marginally beats it)